# Flutter で TextDirection.rtl の結果が予想と異なる

Tags: flutter

最近Flutterを触り始めたのでかなり初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
`TextDirection.rtl`と`TextDirection.ltr`の動作がよくわかりません。
下記のプログラムを実行したのですが、予想と違います。
なぜなのでしょうか。

**実行結果**

- `TextDirection.ltr` の場合

  画面の中央に「Hello, World!」と表示。
  こちらは予想と一致。
- `TextDirection.rtl` の場合

  画面の中央に「!Hello, World」と表示。
  予想は「!dlroW olleH」だったのですが、なぜ予想と違うのでしょうか。

---

**プログラム全体**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
    Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, World!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,　//ここを.ltrにも変更した
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: 参考: [right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535185)

Comment: @cubick そもそも英語はRTL言語ではないから`TextDirection.rtl`では変に表示されるということですか？

Answer (score 0):

下記ソースやってみてください。

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const Center(
    child: Text("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
  ));
}
```